# How do I decrypt logs encrypted in PBEWithMD5AndDES on logstash?

Tags: encryption, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have logs which are encrypted using Java jasypt-1.92 in **PBEWithMD5AndDES** algorithm.
What I need is to decrypt these logs in **Logstash** before sending them to elasticsearch/filters-grok.

Configuration file looks like this,

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/ELK Stack/logstash-2.4.0/qa1/perf/PerformanceLogger.2016-09-14.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "../bulk.sincedb"
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
    match => { "message" => "  \| %{CRID:crid} \| %{TIME:time} \| (?:|%{TRANSID:TRANSID}) \| %{DATA:thread} \| %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}  \| %{DATA} \| %{DATA:method} \| %{POSINT:lineNo} \| %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    add_tag => "%{loglevel}"
   }
   cipher {
        algorithm =>  "des-cbc" 
        key => "somekey1"
        iv_random_length => 8
        cipher_padding => 1
        source => "msg"
        target => "msg"
        base64 => true
        mode => "decrypt"
    }
}output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
        index => "logstash-performance-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

While going through logstash documentations found that decryption can be achieved by using **[filter plugin - Cipher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-cipher.html)** .
But I could not find the right replacement for PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm from the list of algorithms supported by this cipher plugin of logstash.

It would help a lot if anybody could suggest the correct algorithm or the right approach to achieve this, like something that I could tinker in logstash to take encrypted log and decrypt it. I could have run java or someother application to decrypt the log before passing to logstash, but this would add an extra dependent step which I want to avoid.

Comment: MD5 is a hash. It can't be _decrypted_.

Comment: On another note, if you encrypt for security reasons, using a hash functions is a *really* bad idea. Data is lost in the process and as I said, you can't reverse it.

Comment: Hi @Fairy, I have a script that can decrypt these logs. So, I believe its possible to decrypt the logs. Plus, jasypt-1.92 lib also provides an API to decrypt logs encrypted in PBEWithMD5AndDES.

Comment: Either you modify the cipher filter plugin to add the decryption algo or you use the ruby filter, with the decryption algo.

Comment: Well, I am ready to modify cipher plugin, but I have never worked on ruby before and logstash is very new to me so it will take some time on this @baudsp . And what do you mean by ruby filter with decrypt algo?

Comment: Well, you can use the [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to execute ruby code, which is done only in the configuration file, which may be easier than modifying a plugin